# VSCode PowerShell 0.11.0 Debug Console is no longer used - How do I "correctly" use VSCode now?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am still a relatively new PowerShell coder, and I have been successfully using the PowerShell extension v0.8.0 for Visual Studio Code.  I could write a script, press <kbd>F5</kbd>, and happily see my output.

Today I noticed there was an upgrade to v0.11.0, so I clicked the install believing that newer = better.

Unfortunately, now whenever I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to execute my script, I get this error:

> "The Debug Console is no longer used for PowerShell debugging.  Please
>   use the 'PowerShell Integrated Console' to execute commands in the
>   debugger.  Run the 'PowerShell: Show Integrated Console' command to
>   open it."

I can't say I've been smart enough to learn more than basics, and never really knew how to use the debugger, but I was getting by.  With this error, however, does this mean that every time I want to execute my script, I have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and then type out things like I was at a console window?  For now, I've found a workaround by clicking in the editor window and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>.  I was hoping to start reading [an article on debugging](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2017/02/06/debugging-powershell-script-in-visual-studio-code-part-1/), but it seems like the extension update has rendered the material obsolete.

This seems like a huge step back in terms of usability, but I'm not sure if it's really a bug for the extension developer, or I'm just not skillfull enough to use the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that happens now is the output is to the powershell integrated terminal. So make sure that the Terminal tab is active. Then hitting F5 works as normal (before).

My launch.json looks like:

```
{
    "type": "PowerShell",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "PowerShell Launch (current file)",
    "script": "${file}",
    "args": [],
    "cwd": "${file}"
}
```

Comment: Mine looks the same.  I have noticed now that if I don't have the focus set to the integrated terminal, then I get the error about the debugger.  There's also some other weird issues where it gets caught up on removed breakpoints, or crashes the debugger if I don't remember to select focus on the terminal, etc.  Thank you for the hint on setting focus!